# Available space not equal to the sum of space taken by all the apps listed on iOS 9

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I have one iPhone 4s 8GB version which I updated to iOS 9.3.5 and when I see the storage available, I got 4.2 GB after installing some apps. When I counted the sum total of storage consumed by all apps, it was only < 300 MB. But, it showed that the usage is 866 MB.

I tried hard resetting the phone, (Erase all content) and after restart, I selected Setup new iPhone (instead of restoring from backup). However, I have restored backup of WhatsApp from WhatsApp app itself.

The iCloud backup size of WhatsApp is also 5.1MB only and that of the entire phone is < 100MB only. I have gone through this post and did the same way, but still [iOS available space doesn't add up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177412/ios-available-space-doesnt-add-up) and also from [iPhone available space: significant difference between iTunes and iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162825/iphone-available-space-significant-difference-between-itunes-and-iphone) but still, there is 500MB missing somewhere?

I don't currently have Windows OS/Mac to install iTunes, I use Linux Mint and iTunes doesn't detect iPhone in Wine (on Linux) and I also can't install VirtualBox due to some reasons.

If the solution to this problem requires iTunes, then I may need to install Windows.

Edit: I updated my iPhone from iOS 7.0 to 8.4.1 and then finally to 9.3.5. After that I erased all its contents. Are the iOS downlodaed installation files still there on my iPhone?

Comment: I would check to see why you can't install Virtual Box.

Comment: Just because, I don't want to clutter up my linux os with all that. I would like to know after I install, how to clean it up.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford If I have iTunes, I can see how much space the 'Other' is occupying, but how do I clean it? If backup be the only way, then I could as well do it with iCloud (since I have very less, backup 10 MB or so), apart from just 'knowing' how much space does the 'Other' occupy do I have any other use of iTunes for this problem?